# How to store value of toggle button in database in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm having a button which says whether the user is active user or not. How to store the value of the button database. I mean, if I activate the user using the button click the value should be '1' in the database. Else it should be '0'.

`<%= f.button ( f.object.active? ? "Active" : "Inactive" ), class: 'btn btn-brand m-btn m-btn--air m-btn--custom', html: { margin: '0 auto' }, id: 'active_button', onclick: 'change()' %>`

Here I'm trying to toggle between active and inactive.

```
<script>
  function change() {
    var toggle = document.getElementById("active_button");
    if (toggle.innerHTML == "Active") {
      toggle.innerHTML = "Inactive";
    } else {
      toggle.innerHTML = "Active";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: add boolean column 'activated' in user table.

Comment: added. But the value of the field doesn't change. How to customize it?

Comment: can you paste your view erb file what you are trying to do? @ParvathyManivannan

Comment: @ParvathyManivannan Can you please add some code what you done?

Comment: @ParvathyManivannan What did you write in onclick function?

Comment: I think if you want to us JS for this, you're going to need to make a fetch call to your controller to update the user's active column. Otherwise you could just have the button submit to your controller normally and the value would be updated as the page refreshed.

Comment: How to make a call to controller in this case? @MikeHeft

Comment: @ParvathyManivannan, with JS fetch or normal rails submission?

Comment: With rails submission @MikeHeft

Comment: You can add a custom route/action. Route- `get :activate, to: 'users#activate'`. Then in your `UsersController` you can have an activate action. `def activate; current_user.update_attributes(active: true); end` Then you can just have a small form that just contains the that submits to that controller/action

Comment: @ParvathyManivannan Add ajax call for updating value of database field onclick of that button.

Comment: @ParvathyManivannan are your issue resolved?

Comment: You can take boolean variable in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle Button works like a radio button. So you have to create a column for that in database and save the value in database like any other field.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you either add a boolean column in the database or use a state machine ([AASM for example](https://github.com/aasm/aasm)) to manage state

Comment: We can use AASM gem when we have multiple statuses. Not for one or two. It is not good practice.